# "Beforehand" vs. "in advance".

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Are "beforehand" and "in advance" totally interchangeable? Or are there cases where one of them is more suitable than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience (native American English speaker), the word **beforehand** is not really used as it is typically defined. I was actually surprised when I looked [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/beforehand) and saw "in advance" and "in anticipation" included in the definition. I don't feel those nuances when I hear "beforehand".

I'm actually having a difficult time explaining **beforehand** simply because it isn't often used in everyday language. I think the best way to understand it is something like: **beforehand is a way to avoid using a prepositional phrase.** For example, you could state:

> I'll finish the report before the meeting.

OR

> I'll finish the report beforehand.

They both have the same meaning and I don't detect any significant difference in nuance. However, the second would only be stated if it is clear that you are talking about a meeting (because it was discussed earlier).

Also, I'm not confident if this sensation is shared, but I believe that **beforehand** sounds slightly lazy (and consequently a little less formal). It sounds like you are sacrificing explicitness and clarity for ease.

**In advance** is a bit easier to understand. **In advance** always implies that you are doing something **earlier than absolutely necessary.**

Answer (score 2):

*"Totally"* interchangeable, no.

Although **in advance** and **beforehand** have similar meanings, one takes complements and the other does not.

In advance *of planting*, they added fertilizer to the soil.

Beforehand of planting.... <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

They evacuated in advance of the hurricane.

They evacuated beforehand (of) the hurricane <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> Are "beforehand" and "in advance" totally interchangeable?

I guess, no.

> Are there cases where one of them is more suitable than the other?

Yes, there are.

> Thanks **in advance**.

is correct but I've never heard someone saying

> Thanks **beforehand**.

Comment: Can you think of any other situation except these two examples?

Comment: Could you provide some examples or references to back up your assertions why these are **not** normally interchangeable?  One data point does not decide a trend, and "thanks before" might just be an exception.

Comment: @Andrew: I never claimed it to be a trend. OP asked if there's any case where the two aren't interchangeable and I simply provided an example. What part of my answer made you think that I'm talking about a trend?

Comment: @7_R3X  "I guess, no".  I'm just asking if you can improve the answer to where it's less of a *guess*, based on personal anecdote.